# Where should I place child collection methods in ASP.NET Web Api?

Tags: .net, rest, asp.net-web-api, semantics

This question is probably debatable, but I think there should be a solution that has more advantages than the other.

If I have two controllers - UsersController and ContactsController and the corresponding URIs to them /api/users/ and /api/contacts/, I want to be able to select all the contacts that belong to a particular user like this:

```
GET /api/users/1/contacts/
```

So, my question is what the better approach is - to put the actual .NET method in the UsersController or in the ContactsController and why.

Comment: I think, it is clear. You put your method in Contacts controller. Well, because you get contacts. User id is your criteria. But on the other side, not sure if that logic supported by `GET /api/users/1/contacts/` unless you configure specific routing.

Comment: Yeap, you should just add an Route attribute to your .NET method and everything fits in perfectly. Thanks :)